# Windows 8 delete key always delete file permanently

Tags: windows-8

Don't know why, but now my Delete key works the same as Shift + Delete which shows a 'Do you want to delete XXX permanently dialog. And it does not go through Recycle Bin anymore. How so?

I am using the Windows 8 x64 edition.

**Update:** My recycle bin setting is fine, that's why this is tricky. But the "Display delete confirmation dialog" check is checked and grayed out. That's one bit that is. The radio button of "Don't move files to recycle bin" is not checked.

Comment: After some intense Googling of `windows permanent delete`: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure what your problem is but you could have sticky keys enabled(five shift key presses) or you can edit the two following polices to see if it helps you out.

For both of the following ways, run `gpedit.msc` by clicking on Start and typing into the search box. Navigate to `User Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Windows Explorer`.

To give yourself full control of the "Display delete confirmation dialog" check box, double click `Display confirmation dialog when deleting files` and change this to `Not Configured`.

For control to edit if files are deleted to the recyclying bin or if they are permanently deleted, double click `Do not move deleted file to the Recycle Bin` and change this to `Not Configured`.

With both of the above set to "not configured" you should be able to edit all of the recycling bin properties.

Comment: wow, it's a detailed, actionable answer. Will try your suggestions